# How can I remove the first page of multiple pdf files in a directory? PYTHON

Tags: python, pdf

I need to remove the first page of multiple pdf files in a directory.  I am an elementary level python user and I have cobbled together the following code from bits & pieces of other code that I have.  However, I cannot get it to work. Does anything jump out at anyone?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

import os, sys

directory_name = 'emma'


for filename in directory_name:
    print 'name: %s' % filename

    output_file = PdfFileWriter()
    input_handle = open(filename+'.pdf', 'rb')
    input_file = PdfFileReader(input_handle)

    num_pages = input_file.getNumPages()

    print "document has %s pages \n" % num_pages

    for i in xrange(1, num_pages):
        output_file.addPage(input_file.getPage(i))
        print 'added page %s \n' % i

    output_stream = file(filename+'-stripped.pdf','wb')
    output_file.write(output_stream)

    output_stream.close()
    input_handle.close()
```

Error message:

```
    input_handle = open(filename+'.pdf', 'rb')
        IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a.pdf'
```

Comment: First of all, please specify the meaning of "cannot get it to work". Second, assuming the answer to the 1st question is "the resulting document is created but incomplete", examine the internals of reader and writer objects (perhaps, there's an underlying "document" object) to see what is missing in the 2nd one. I guess it's additional entities besides pages.

Comment: Well, I am getting an error which is: input_handle = open(filename+' .pdf', 'rb'>  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a.pdf'

Comment: Then it's exactly what it reads: the OS cannot find the file path you passed to the `open()` call. It's not even connected to `PyPDF2`. Please do a reasonable amount of preliminary diagnostics and/or googling yourself before asking questions on the Net and making others waste their time on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code iterates over "emma" and tries to open `e.pdf`, `m.pdf` (twice), `a.pdf`. Your error on `a.pdf` means the first two actually exist, which is interesting enough on its own.

But to your problem, you need to use [os.listdir](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.listdir) or [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob#glob.glob) to actually get the filenames within the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the code to Python 3, just in case somebody wants to use it:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader 

import os, glob, sys

os.chdir(r'data_path')
filename_lst = glob.glob('*.pdf')
print('number of files: {}'.format(len(filename_lst)))

save_path = '...' # if you want to save the results somewhere else

for filename in filename_lst:
    print('name: {}'.format(filename))

    output_file = PdfWriter()
    input_handle = open(filename, 'rb')
    input_file = PdfReader (input_handle)

    num_pages = len(input_file.pages)

    print("document has {} pages \n".format(num_pages))

    for i in range(1, num_pages):
        output_file.add_page(input_file.pages[i])

    output_stream = open(save_path + filename, 'wb')
    output_file.write(output_stream)

    output_stream.close()
    input_handle.close()
```